How to open App Clip from scan application
I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI for scanning and have created another app clip. I've generated a QR code for the second app, set up the local experience, and everything seems fine so far and when i try to scan QR fro camera it opens app clip. However, when I scan the QR code using the application, it opens Safari instead of launching the app clip from the scanning application. What should I do?!
 if let url = URL(string: "https://example.restapp.com/restourant") {
                    let options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: options) { success in
                        if success {
                            print("Opened App Clip successfully")
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to open App Clip")
                        }
                    }
                }

